# scala pattern matching - variable

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

While I was reading [this (page 14)](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/chap0.pdf) I came across this algorithm:

```
function fib2(n)
    if n = 0 return 0
    create an array f[0 : : : n]
    f[0] = 0, f[1] = 1
    for i = 2 : : : n:
        f[i] = f[i  1] + f[i  2]
    return f[n]
```

If I wanted to implement this in Scala using pattern matching, is there a way to create a List in the pattern match part in order to use it in the final return statement?

these are great answers, but I think I'd still like to know if it's possible to define a variable that you only use in your pattern match. I know you can do it in Haskell, but I'm wondering if it's doable in Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a refactoring of jeela's solution. I think it's better to work always with the head, as it is much faster. The final `reverse` doesn't hurt much.

```
def fib(s:Int) = {
  def f(s:Int):List[Int] = s match {
    case x if x < 0 => Nil
    case 0 => List(0)
    case 1 => List(1,0)
    case _ => val fibs = f(s-1); (fibs.head + fibs.tail.head) :: fibs
  }
  f(s).reverse
}
```

Comment: this is in fact what i was looking for `val fibs = f(s-1); (fibs.head + fibs.tail.head) :: fibs` I suppose it's "less functional" because of the val, but it answers the question of how to define a variable within the scope of pattern matching.

Answer (score 13):

```
lazy val fib: Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(0,Stream.cons(1, fib.zip(fib.tail).map(p => p._1 + p._2)))
```

**fib.take(n).last** will return the result
 
another stream based solution. It defines a infinite Fibonacci sequence. Yes it is rescue and infinite definition, but all computations are performed while take is called.
[image]
just check here for more interesting code.
[link](http://www.scala-blogs.org/2007/12/project-euler-fun-in-scala.html)

Comment: +1 for a great answer. Can you break this down a bit for a n00b? I'm not clear on the fib.zip (and fib.tail) part.

Comment: @Ramy Try this at the REPL: `val s = Seq(1, 2, 3); println(s.tail); println(s zip s.tail)`

Answer (score 10):

I don't see much need for pattern matching here. The straightforward translation to Scala would look basically the same: create an array `f` and loop over indices `2 until n`.

```
def fib(n: Int): Array[Int] = {
  val f = new Array[Int](math.max(2, n))
  f(0) = 0
  f(1) = 1
  for (i <- 2 until n)
    f(i) = f(i-1) + f(i-2)
  f
}
```

If you want to get fancier, how about a [lazy stream](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_14.html)?

```
def fibFrom(a: Int, b: Int): Stream[Int] = a #:: fibFrom(b, a + b)
fibFrom(0, 1).take(8).toList // returns List(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using lazy streams is better approach but just to flex my muscles:

```
def fib(s:Int):List[Int] = s match {
  case 0 => Nil
  case 1 => 0::fib(s-1)
  case 2 => 0::1::fib(s-2)
  case _ => fib(s-1):::fib(s-1).takeRight(2).sum::Nil
}
```